# How to add custom event on bubble in ForceDirectedTree amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

How to change color of the child bubble on click or add hover effect on child bubble.
I tried like this:

```
networkSeries.nodes.template.events.on('hit', e=> {
  e.target.dataItem.color = e.target.dataItem.color.lighten(-0.2)
  //networkSeries.deepInvalidate()
  //networkSeries.invalidate()
})
```

but it does not refreshing.
Here is example code: http://jsfiddle.net/gasnvf0j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the color to `fill` or `stroke` to see the result:

```
const newColor = e.target.dataItem.color.lighten(-0.2)
e.target.dataItem.color = newColor
e.target.fill = newColor
```